# Prepend a Letter and Counter Value to every cell in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2010

How can I prepend a Letter and an Integer Counter to every cell in a column in Excel?

Example:

```
 **Name**
 Ramesh
 Garry
 Rohan
```

Expected

```
 **Name**
 R1Ramesh
 R2Garry
 R3Rohan
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your header is in the first row, in a separate column any of the below would suffice:

1. `="R" & ROW(A2)-1 & A2`
2. `=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,"R",ROW(A2)-1,A2)`
3. `=CONCATENATE("R",ROW(A2)-1,A2)`

---

[image]

---

You are essentialy associating the Row number of your name to the counter. Since there is a header in place, we offset by `-1`. If your header is in the 2nd Row, you would offset by `-2`

Comment: if you are going to use an anchor cell in `ROW()` just use `A1`: `="R" &ROW(A1) & A2`

Comment: I thought about that but it is less intuitive if the table doesn't start in top of sheet. In my mind linking everything to the same row is cleaner @ScottCraner

Comment: Which is why I always us `$ZZ1` then one knows it is a counter and not a reference to a value in a cell.

Comment: The way I see it is it gets messy if the OP starts in row 5, then they either need to use MIN() or do the math to get it to `1` with `$ZZ1` we know the counter will always start at 1

Comment: Is `$ZZ1` a standard or personal method? Def like that approach

Comment: Personal, got tired of having to explain the math, like you did with your last paragraph.  using a cell that is outside the normal use does two things.  First it helps the user understand that it is just a counter and not referencing a value in a cell.  Second, formula calc by changes to their predecessors.  This way the formula will most likely not get kicked into calc for changes to data that is not related.

Answer (score 2):

In OFFICE 365 with dynamic array formula `SEQUENCE()`

```
="R"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A5))&A2:A5
```

[image]

Comment: Wonder when these are going to be pushed to lower levels of excel. Will be interesting to see when Dynamic Array formulas start to dominate in solutions

Comment: I doubt Excel will ever make them available to earlier versions.  I believe there is too much back end design required to integrate.  The Dynamic Array functionality extends beyond the new formula to how and when Excel handles all array type formula.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. Guess the norm will be to document both (which we have now done twice today lol)